# Why is async required on methods that call async methods?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Consider this (textbook) sample dart code:

```
// Sequential processing using async and await.
main() async {
  await expensiveA();
  await expensiveB();
  doSomethingWith(await expensiveC());
}
```

I understand that await will wait for the result of the future "expensiveA" to complete before continuing.

But what I don't understand is why main() must itself be declared async? Apparently you have to do this or the program will not compile. But why can a synchronous method not await the result of asynchronous calls?

I understand this must be a newbie question but I have not been able to find an answer for this yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `async`/`await`, which was only added a while ago to Dart, you would have written like

```
main() {
  var result = expensiveA()
    .then((_) => expensiveB())
    .then((_) => expensiveC()); // the Future returned by expensiveC will be returned because `doSomethingWith` is not awaited in your code
  result.then(doSomethingWith);
  return result;
}
```

An async call returns a `Future`, and you can pass a function to it's `then` method to be called when the async call completes.

This code

```
main() async {
  await expensiveA();
  await expensiveB();
  doSomethingWith(await expensiveC()); // doSomethingWith is not awaited
}
```

get's rewritten to something similar to the code in the first code block, before it's executed.

This shows that `async`/`await` doesn't change the nature of the code, it only changes the syntax to something that looks more like sync code.

`async` is a marker that the code in the method needs to be rewritten, and this marker allows the use of `await`, without rewriting `await` would have no meaning.

`async` implicitly returns the last `await`ed `Future`, so that the caller is able to `await` the completion of this `Future`.
Because a `Future` is returned, strong mode requires the return type to match.

Comment: So using async on a method is basically a hint to the compiler that it has to rewrite the await methods to use Futures. I guess I understand but it is a bit confusing and not so logical that if method A wants to invoke and wait for async method B to return, then A must suddenly also be async, with all the consequences that follow to everyone else who called A before. It would have been better if the compiler understood what was going on, rather than this "preprocessor-ish" approach.

Comment: Async is quite confusing to many at the beginning. There are lots and lots of similar questions (also for other languages).
async execution is contagious. There is no way to go back to sync execution. If you don't want to await calls on the caller site, there is no need to add `async`.  
async execution has serious impact on your API and you need to consider carefully how to design your code. Making it implicit would in my opinion also be confusing in many cases.

Comment: But it seems that dart makes it more confusing than it has to be. If a method awaits all of its internal async method invocations, then what is the reason for that method to also have to be asynchronous? Since the last async call it made already completed, the method itself will complete immediately. There is no difference between that and a synchronous call. Yet all the code around the method must now also await, and you can't use the method in certain situations (like in a Flutter setState(fn) function). And for no really good logical reason.

Comment: To await anything it has already to be async. This is not Dart specific. Async execution looks quite similar in other languages (that also have `asnyc`/`await` otherwise there is `.then(...)` or similar everywhere). If you look at the first code block in answer, you'll see that async execution is about functions being passed around, that get called by the receiver when an event happens (like the function `(_) => await expensiveB()` is passed to `.then(...)`. Async execution isn't just some weird Dart behavior. I think it's great that they were able to make it this comfortable at all.

Comment: The reason why main() needs to be async has to be because it is too complicated for the compiler to figure out if main() really does await all of its asynchronous calls. If it could figure that out, then it would realize that "await main()" would always be a no-op. Is that not correct? I mean am I missing something about what await means?

Comment: So I learned a bit now. In dart async methods *always* return a future but they execute synchronously until the first "await" call. So it does make sense to await main(), because it returns the instant main() begins to await another method.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your last 2 comments. If you mark the method `async` it's know it will return a future. The Dart analyzer and the VM therefore require the return type to be `Future`. It would be too complicated to have a different behavior for different situations, because in 99% the caller wants to wait for that `Future`. Only if you have fire-and-forget calls you can return a result in a sync way, but this won't allow to return a result of any async calls, just other values that are calculated synchronically within the same method.

Comment: I just mean that at some point you will need the result of said async method. At some point you will have to await it. In the example above, it's the main() method that needs the result of expensiveA(). So it awaits the future to complete and gets the result. So why the need for main() to be asynchronous as well? main() is not asynchronous, it just invokes methods in some sequence and each time it waits for the result. In stead anyone calling main() now has to "await main()" which does absolutely nothing because there's nothing to wait for. That was the starting point.

Comment: `async` is not for the caller to be able to await, it's for the method itself to support `await`, otherwise it would need to use `someAsync().then((val) => moreCode());` instead of `await somaAsync(); moreCode();`. That a method with `async` returns a `Future` is to make it possible for the caller to wait until the called async execution is done, before executing more of its own code, no matter if it wants to use the return value of the call or not.

Comment: In unit tests the test framework calls `main()` and it waits for the `main()` method to complete registering tests (that might as well do that async), before it starts executing the registered tests. If it wouldn't need to wait, it could just ignore the returned `Future`, but if `main()` didn't return a `Future`, the test framework would not be able to determine when `main()` is done registering tests. Async execution just invokes a call and continues to execute other sync code. A method that makes async calls returns long before the execution is completed.

Comment: The `Future` allows to get notified after the return, when the execution is **actually** completed.

Answer (score 2):

*Why can a synchronous method not await the result of asynchronous calls?*
Because that would mean **blocking** until expensive call is finished.

However Dart is [single threaded with event loop](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop), so having easy way to block whole Dart app would be extremely dangerous.

Comment: But I want to block. I need the result of expensive call.

Comment: Yes you need the result and only then to continue in caller function's code -
 exactly what await construct will give to you.

Comment: You generally don't want to block in the way that system stops to respond. Caller function is suspended when it reaches await, system lets your asynchronous expensive function to execute and then resumes caller function when it's finished. Note that expensive functions typically waits for a network, disk etc. and system has plenty of time to handle other requests and stay responsive.

Comment: You do not want to *block* a single-threaded system to wait for the result of an expensive computation, because then there is no way to do that computation. That is what asynchronous computation is about—the ability to *wait* without blocking. The consequence is that any function that waits for an asynchronous result must itself be asynchronous; it cannot return a result immediately, and it cannot block, and it must return something when you call it, so there is no way it can return the correct result directly.

Comment: @lrn async/await does not give you the ability to wait without blocking, it just allows parts of your code to run in parallel. If i need the result of expensiveA then I can start expensiveA() now and do some useful work while it executes, but eventually I will need the result from expensiveA before I can continue. I *have* to await it. If this happens in method performComplexThing, then I simply don't see why performComplexThing *also* has to be async.

Comment: @DafeŠimonek Yes precisely. But why does the method that performs the "await expensiveA()" also have to be declared async? It is not async, it just waits for the completion of an async method call.

Comment: Method that performs the "await expensiveA()" **is asynchronous** and has to be as @lm explained. I created small demo taht you can run in dartpad and see the order of execution from debug prints: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b67b6b5a5e7e6db2900d41e64a38a65f

Comment: All functions in Dart return synchronously when they are called. An asynchronous function is just one that synchronously returns a future. If your function contains an `await`, then it must wait for that to complete before executing the rest of the body, including the return statements. Having an `await` implies that returns are not executed synchronously, so the function *needs* to return a `Future` instead, it doesn't know which value to return yet. That is why `await` is only allowed in `async` functions - they are the only functions that *can* delay their return statements.